# Resizeable Image using twitter-bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying twitter's framework to develop my own site and I want my image to resize as the browser size is decreased. I am confused and tried everything but couldn't come up with a solution here is my structure

**HTML**

```
<section id="intro">
      <div class="row" id="ruby">
        <div class="span6" id="heading">
          <h1>Journey Into Ruby and Beyond</h1>
          <p>A blog about my journey into ruby, my experiences and lots of fun!</p>
        </div>

        <div class="span6" id="pic" align="right">
           <p>Akash Soti<br>RoR Developer<br>@xyz company </p>
        </div>
    </section><!--/intro-->
```

**CSS**

```
#ruby.row{

margin-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}

#pic{

background: url(img/Akash.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 150px;
width: 200px;
margin-left: 200px;

}

#pic img{

max-width:100% ;
    max-height:100% ;
    display:block;

}

#pic p{
position: relative;
right: 110px;
margin-top: 90px;
margin-left: 0px;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Used to background-size properites

Comment: Unless you _really_ need to use your own CSS, it is all here http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#thumbnails

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Twitter bootstrap is designed to make images (and layout) responsive, that is images in your content:

`<img src="path/to/images.jpg" alt="some">`

Not the images you used as background-images in CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use

```
@media (max-width: 699px) {
#pic{
background: url(img/Akash.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 100px;
width: 150px;
margin-left: 200px;
}
}
```

But if you want responsive design, try to avoid pixels, use %. And if your background meant to be picture(e.g. photo, pic) but not background-kind of image, use `<img>` instead